# How can I change link in my dropdown menu

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I change links in my dropdown menu in worpress. Menu looks like this

```
ITEM 1 || ITEM 2  || ITEM 3 || ITEM 4
       || ITEM 2.1||        || ITEM 4.1||
       || ITEM 2.2||        || ITEM 4.1||
       || ITEM 2.3||        || ITEM 4.1||
```

I want that when the user clicks on the section 2 section 2.1 will open and the same result in section 4 when user click section 4.1 will open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to load all the drop downs, and use Jquery to hide them. Next you could display then based on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".subdropdown").show();
});

if($(".dropdown1").val()==item-2){
$(".subdropdown").show();
}
```

Hope this helps, this is just an example buy i hope you can expand from this .